# Как достучаться ко всем элементам массива справа?

Tags: javascript

Функція getLeaders приймає масив чисел, та повертає масив Лідерів

Пояснення: Число вважається Лідером, якщо воно більше за суму всіх елементів справа від нього.

```
function getLeaders(numbers) {
    let result = []

    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1]) {
            result.push(numbers[i])
        }
    }

    return result
}

console.log(getLeaders([4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 3]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  let sumRight = 0;
  for (let i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (numbers[i] > sumRight) {
      result.push(numbers[i]);
    }
    sumRight += numbers[i];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Я немного отредактировала ваш код с учетом ответа, который был дан. Только нужно использовать метод unshift() в вашем случае.

```
 ***********************************************

function getLeaders(numbers) {
      const result = [];
      let sumRight = 0;
    
      for (let i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (numbers[i] > sumRight) {
          result.unshift(numbers[i]);
        }
        sumRight += numbers[i];
      }
    
      return result;
    }
```